# Google Analytics 4 - Data Not Showing For Custom Time Parameters

Tags: google-analytics-4

I am not seeing data when I set custom parameters from June 1st 2022 to August 31st 2022, but I do see data when I click "Last Calendar Year" and look at all 12 months of 2022. However, I just need to see the data from those 3 months in 2022 alone.

[Data Showing for full 12 months of 2022](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jesd6.jpg)

[Data Not Showing for 3 months during 2022](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etKEh.jpg)

I tried restarting GA4 and entering multiple time frame parameters.